# Forms authentication allows AD password expired users to login

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, forms-authentication

I am having issue with Active Directory password expired users.
They can login to application and access application though password is expired.
When i try to run same code from local it give me Membership.ValidateUser as "false" ( pointing to same Active Directory)

Why there is diffference on Windows Server 2008 R2 IIS 7 and my Windows 7 IIS 7?

Is there any specific setting on IIS or AD i need to do?
My application - VSTS 2010, ASP.NET 4.0, C# 4.0

Can anyone please help?

Comment: You're sure Integrated Windows Authentication, and NO other method is enabled?

Comment: Lance, how can i check that? in my website Authentication - Anonymous and Forms authentication is enabled.  I am using IIS 7 on both my server and local but behavior is different for login

Comment: Anonymous authentication will let anyone log in.  It's not checking AD credentials.  I'm not sure about Forms authentication.

Comment: Since you use forms authentication, which means the user credentials are validated by you, not IIS, you have to check what kind of approach is used by your code. If you use Windows authentication, IIS won't let such users in.

Comment: I have anonymous access and Form authentication enabled on both my local and server. I am using base Membership.ValidateUser to validate the user. I think this is IIS or other server setting issue because same code run on my local and it does not validate user if password is expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Server 2008 R2 behavior is different. Somehow it allows though Change Password on Next logon is checked.

Please share your experience.